# Google API for distance doesn't consider traffic when calculate time duration between two points

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

As it is mentioned on The Google Maps Distance Matrix API - departure time is used to receive trip duration considering current traffic conditions.

I tried to get time between points in different days for example:
Fri, 02 Oct 2015 14:10:45 GMT [Friday Calculation](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Kantar+Media+Switzerland+AG,+Bahnhofstrasse+4,+3073+G%C3%BCmligen&destinations=Turneo+AG,+Industrie+Neuhof+21,+3422+Kirchberg&mode=driving&language=en-US&departure_time=1443795045)
and in the response duration is 22 min

When I set date with less traffic Sun, 04 Oct 2015 01:10:45 GMT [Sunday Calculation](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Kantar+Media+Switzerland+AG,+Bahnhofstrasse+4,+3073+G%C3%BCmligen&destinations=Turneo+AG,+Industrie+Neuhof+21,+3422+Kirchberg&mode=driving&language=en-US&departure_time=1443921045)
the response duration is again 22min.

I think the time durations should be different if in calculations are considered current traffic!

Comment: Yes it probably should.  According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters) though _"Google Maps API for Work customers can specify the departure_time to receive trip duration considering current traffic conditions."_  Are you a Google Maps API for Work customer?

Answer (score 1):

Just set `departure_time=now` in your query options. note `now` shouldn't be specified as a timestamp.
You will see a response with `duration_in_traffic` as a child to the elements tag or keyword